# Is there a tool for benchmarking scrolling speed of browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, mouse-scroll, scrolling, firefox-extensions

As the title asks, is there a tool for browser scrolling speed?

I'm working on graphics and need a numbered performance of scrolling.
I saw some mail threads regarding firefox-scrolling benchmark, but not able to find a proper tool to get a performance for fireox scrolling speed.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a new tab in your Firefox browser and type `about:config`.
2. type `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount` in the search bar.
3. Change the value from 5 to 60.